# How to move all documents from one collection to a new one with no routing key specified (6.3.0)

Tags: solr, lucene, document-storage

Have a collection c1 that has 400,000 documents and c2 with no documents (new collection).

No routing key is specified in either collection.

Trying to use the migrate Collections API endpoint found/described
[in the documentation.](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-migrate)

Since no routing key is specified I'm not sure what to use for the `split.key` parameter. I have found [this thread](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Migrate-Documents-to-Another-Collection-td4318900.html) that mentions that a `split.key=!` should encompass all documents. This has not proven true in my tests.

Here is my attempted url: `http://solr.node:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=MIGRATE&collection=c1&split.key=!&target.collection=c2&async=1`

This has not worked, and I have tried many iterations of the `split.key` parameter with no avail. Have tried blank, `a!`, `id!`, `id`, `compositeId` and none of them have migrated any documents to the c2 collection.

How does the Migrate function work with no specified routing key? Is there a default value to use to grab all documents that will actually work?

Thank you!

Edit: since no routing key was specified the current router is `compositeId` as solr does that when it is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question with you. I would like to get the answer too.
I only get some answer from SOLR guide.

**split.key**
The routing key prefix. For example, if the uniqueKey of a document is "a!123", then you would use split.key=a!. This parameter is required.
reference: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/collection-management.html